# Why does echo "$a->b->c" fail?

Tags: php

**Edited to clarify the question. The question is about what syntax PHP will accept inside strings, not about whether properties are undefined.**

PHP allows object properties to appear inside strings, like this:

```
$a->b = "Hello, World!"
echo "PHP says: $a->b";
```

But if you try to access properties deeper in the object, a fatal error occurs:

```
$a->c->d = "Hello, World!"
echo "PHP says: $a->c->d";
```

You have to place the reference outside the string to make it work:

```
$a->c->d = "Hello, World!"
echo "PHP says: " . $a->c->d;
```

Why doesn't PHP syntax accept this form inside a string?

Comment: May be `c` index not exist? Could you show more codes?

Comment: Is $a a variable or a class?

Comment: may c does not exist.

Comment: You need to show what `$a` and `$a->b` are.

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski `$a` is variable, even if it contains object (not class).

Comment: Sorry but this is like asking why `echo $x;` does not print 42.

Comment: If it fails then it simply means that the property b of the object a is not an object or maybe it is object but does not have property c.

Comment: it will work if b is also object and class member of that class which belongs to $a and c is member variable of $b class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how [PHPs string interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) works. You are using the ["simple" variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple), which means that

```
echo "PHP says: $a->c->d";
```

is parsed as

```
echo "PHP says: {$a->c}->d";
```

thus PHP tries to interpolate the value of `$a->b` into the string. This doesn't work as that's an object, and you get the fatal error:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

If `$a->c` was a string value, for example `"foo"`, the output would be:

> PHP says: foo->d

To achieve what you want you need to use the ["complex" variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
echo "PHP says: {$a->c->d}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$a` is object with `b` property, while `$a->b` is not object or doesn't have `c` property?